# Static route + pptp VPN for communication between different networks through internet

Tags: router, ppp, static-routes

I'm trying to configure two routers that are responsible for two different networks. I have a 4G tplink router TL MR6400 in one side, and a 4G Teltonika router RUTXR1 on the other side. I want the teltonika to be the pptp client and tplink to be the pptp server. The teltonika has a private IP 192.168.20.1 while the tp link has a private IP 192.168.16.1. I tried to configure the PPTP VPN and it is working unidirectional, I can ping the server side but can't ping the client. The VPN pool is 10.7.0.11 - 20. I have a suspicion that the server doesn't know the client network although the client know the server network. Besides this I also have a router connected to teltonika (Mikrotik) that will manage a small LAN. The teltonika is just to give 4G internet to the mikrotik. So, here is the full network:

192.168.180.0/24 (Mikrotik) <-> 192.168.20.0/24 (Teltonika) <-> Internet <-> 192.168.16.0/24 (TP-Link).

My question is, what route should I put in tp-link in order to ping a device in network 192.168.20.0/24 or 192.168.180.0/24?

Thank you

Comment: Here's my standard warning on PPTP questions: PPTP has long been broken (security-wise) and has been deprecated by its creator (Microsoft) for more than a decade now. It should not be used for new deployments (new VPN setups). Vendors kept shipping PPTP after it was known to be broken, just to support anyone who hadn't had a chance to upgrade to a better VPN protocol yet. But it's been long enough at this point that vendors are doing their customers a disservice by still shipping PPTP support as if it's still fine to use.

Comment: Hi, for now this is just for testing, the main purpose of this network is to test a web application (server connected to tp-link) that needs to comunicate with another device that is in the network of mikrotik. For now the security issues are not taken into account. Besides the problem is on the static route, I need to make the tp link recognize the network of mikrotik.